# CAPL using timers as delay causing crash

Tags: delay, capl

I'm trying to edit a script written by someone else in CAPL. The original script works as intended, but my edited version compiles, but has some run-time issues. When I press key 'u' the whole program crashes, as if it's getting stuck in a loop it cannot break. A cut-down version of the code is shown below, for the parts I've edited:

(The original code decrements CMD by 5 each time 'u' is pressed, and increments CMD by 5 each time 'U' is pressed. I want my new script to continuously ramp up and down CMD between my defined limits, at my defined step and time interval indefinitely until 'U' is pressed, which will reset CMD to 0)

```
variables
{

    //Added for my script
    int rampFlag = 0;
    int tmrFlag  = 0;
    long rampRate = 50; //ms
    long rampStep = 1;
    long LimUpper = 100;    //max 350
    long LimLower = -100;   //min -350
    msTimer tmrRamp; 

    //Other existing variables from working script...
}

on start
{
    //No changes for my script
}

//Added for my script:
on timer tmrRamp
{
    //Do nothing
}

on key 'u'
{
    //Working script (commented out) This just decrements CMD every time 'u' is pressed:
    /*CMD = CMD - 5;

    if(CMD < -350)
    {
        CMD = -350;
    }*/

    //Added for my script:

    CMD = 0;

    //ramp up and down the command CMD until key 'U' is pressed

    rampFlag = 1;
    while(rampFlag == 1)
    {

        //ramp up
    while(CMD < LimUpper)
    {
        CMD = CMD + rampStep;   
        setTimer(tmrRamp,rampRate);             //start timer
        while(isTimerActive(tmrRamp) == 1){}    //wait for timer to expire
        //delay_ms(rampRate);    
    }

    //ramp down
    while(CMD > LimLower)
    {
        CMD = CMD - rampStep;
        setTimer(tmrRamp,rampRate);             //start timer
        while(isTimerActive(tmrRamp) == 1){}    //wait for timer to expire
    }
    }
}


on key 'U'
{
    //Working script (commented out) This just increments CMD every time 'U' is pressed:
    /*CMD = CMD + 5;

    if(CMD >= 350)
    {
        CMD = 350;
    }*/

    //Added for my script:
    //Cease ramping up and down the torque request when key 'U' is pressed    

    rampFlag = 0;
    cancelTimer(tmrRamp);
    CMD = 0;
}
```

I tried commenting out the outer while loop in "on key 'u' " in case the "on key 'U' " event statements are unable to be executed while " on key 'u' " statements are running....I was assuming any event could override any other even if it is still executing? Anyway running this still causes everything to freeze when I'm pressing 'u', so I think there is also a problem with the use of my timer functions.

All I want is function similar to delay_ms(), but CAPL doesn't seem to recognise this, so I'm forced to try and use the setTimer and isTimerActive functions.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> I want my new script to continuously ramp up and down CMD between my defined limits, at my defined step and time interval indefinitely until 'U' is pressed, which will reset CMD to 0

In order to avoid nested while loops, I suggest solving this problem by using the "on timer" event. Within it you restart the timer every execution until it is canceled.

```
variables
{
    int rampDirection = 1;
    long rampRate = 50; //ms
    long rampStep = 1;
    long LimUpper = 100;    //max 350
    long LimLower = -100;   //min -350
    msTimer tmrRamp; 
}

on start
{

}


on timer tmrRamp
{
    // currently ramping up
    if(rampDirection == 1) {
        if (CMD < LimUpper)
        {
            CMD = CMD + rampStep
        }
        // max is reached -> start ramping down
        else
        {
            rampDirection = 0;
            CMD = CMD - rampStep;
        }
    }
    // currently ramping down
    else
    {
        if (CMD > LimLower)
        {
            CMD = CDM - rampStep;
        }
        //min is reached start ramping up
        else
        {
            rampDirerction = 1;
            CMD = CDM + rampStep;
        }
    }
    // timer restarts itslef until canceled
    setTimer(tmrRamp,rampRate);
}

on key 'u'
{
    CMD = 0;
    rampDirection = 1; // start with ramping up
    setTimer(tmrRamp,rampRate);
}


 on key 'U'
{
    cancelTimer(tmrRamp);
    CMD = 0;
}
```